# Replace first matching character in string in PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, export-to-csv

In the following string,

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

how could I replace the first colon (and this one only) with a comma so I would get the following string?

```
apache,x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Also, the code has to support a file with multiple lines and replace the first comma in each line only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
PS C:\> $s = 'apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin'
PS C:\> $s -replace '^(.*?):(.*)','$1,$2'
apache,x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Regexp breakdown:

- `^(.*?):`: shortest match between the beginning of the string and a colon (i.e. the text before the first colon).
- `(.*)`: the remainder of the string (i.e. everything after the first colon).

The parantheses group the subexpressions, so they can be referenced in the replacement string as `$1` and `$2`.

*Further explanation:*

- `^` matches the beginning of a string.
- `.*` matches any number of characters (`.` ⇒ any character, `*` ⇒ zero or more times).
- `.*?` does the same, but gives the shortest match (`?`) instead of the longest match. This is called a "non-greedy match".

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! :) Would you mind explaining the role of those characters in your regex? Thanks!

Comment: Terrific! Thank you sir! :)